# Looking for something that can convert input from microphone to a wav file using c++ on mac

Tags: c++, macos

I am looking for an API or something that can read input from the microphone and convert it to a wav file repeatedly but have not found anything. I am on a mac.

I have tried PortAudio, but it seems to be out of date, and the other API's I have found are all for windows, I was wondering if anyone could recommend something that could help me accomplish my task. Thanks.

Comment: You might use Qt for this. Just look at the example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audiorecorder-example.html#